# PostgreSQL cannot convert empty string to (null) date value

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I will use JDBC to push Data into `PostgreSQL`.
So I wrote the `Insert` code like this in Dao.

```JAVA
public void insert(Connection con, List<InsertVo> list) throws Exception{
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    int listSize = list.size();
    int pstmtSetInt = 1;

    try {
        String sql = "insert into tableName "
                + "(colName1,colName2,colName3) " 
                + "values ";
        String addInsertSql = "(?,?,?::date)";
        sql = addInsertQuery(sql, addInsertSql, listSize);
        pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        for (InsertVo vo : list) {
            pstmt.setString(pstmtSetInt++, vo.getColName1()); 
            pstmt.setInt(pstmtSetInt++, vo.getColName2());  
            pstmt.setString(pstmtSetInt++, vo.getColName3()); 
        }
        System.out.println(pstmt);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    } finally {
        try {
            if (pstmt != null) {
                pstmt.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private String addInsertQuery(String sql, String addInsertSql, int listSize) {
    for (int idx = 0; idx < listSize; idx++) {
        sql = sql + addInsertSql;
        if (listSize-1 != idx) {
            sql = sql + ", ";
        }
    }
    return sql;
}
```

There are many `Insert` statements that are repeated when inputted once, so it was written while increasing the number of '()'.
The problem with this code, however, is that if the date part contains a `null` or an empty string like `""`, you get an ERROR.
Since that part is not `not null`, it can be `null` or `""`.
The bottom line is I want to know if there's something other than checking the date part and giving different insert statements.

> The ERROR message looks like this.
>   `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type date: ""`

> I checked again and found that if I change the value to `""` NULL, the ERROR does not go into it.

```
//pstmt.setString(pstmtSetInt++, vo.getColName3());

String dateValue=vo.getColName3();
if (dateValue.equals("")) {
        dateValue = null;
    }
pstmt.setString(pstmtSetInt++, dateValue);
```

> Thank you for your help.

Comment: And you didnt think of including that error here?

Comment: I didn't understand it, but I wonder where to include the error.

Comment: For example in the question

Comment: ERROR occurs in ```:: date``` part of pstmt.

Comment: ```pstmt.setInt(pstmtSetInt++, vo.getColName3());```

Comment: Exception occurs because a value other than date is included here.

Comment: If you get an error, then please include the exception stacktrace in your question.

Comment: The ERROR message looks like this:
```org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type date: ""```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to know if there's something other than checking the date part and giving different insert statements.

You don't need to use a different SQL statement for each case, you just need to tweak the statement so that it won't fail when an empty string is passed:

```sql
INSERT INTO tblname ( ... , col3) VALUES ( ... , NULLIF(?, '')::date)
```

Comment: thank you. Now you know you can use ```NULLIF```.
I've created a separate method that determines that it's null, which makes it easier to code.